# Why I can't use the CATALINA_HOME environment variable?

Tags: command-line, server, bash, environment-variables, tomcat

I am not yet a Linux guy and I have the following problem with environment variable.

So I want to add a permanent environment variable and I do in this way:

I open the **/etc/profile** file and I add this line at the end of this file:

```
CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24
```

Where **/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24** is the folder that contain the tomcat installation (it contains the **bin** TomCat subfolder)

Then I save this file.

So I close the shell and I reopen it and I try to do:

```
andrea@andrea-virtual-machine:/$ sudo ./startup.sh
sudo: ./startup.sh: command not found
```

To start the server instead enter into **/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/bin/** and perform the command.

But as you can see I obtain an error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

- You also need to `export` the variable into the environment as follows:

  ```
  export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24
  ```

Since you are using `/etc/profile`, it won't take effect in X again, until you logout and in again of your xsession, not just your shell.

- Also `sudo` cannot find `./startup.sh`.  You need to be in the same directory as this script.  By enter it, it means first:

  ```
  cd /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/bin/
  ```

Answer (score 5):

`sudo ./startup.sh` command will execute the `startup.sh` script in your current directory.

This you should do:

Add this line to /etc/profile for setting path while booting( Permanent change)

```
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.24
```

To set path temporarily execute above command in the current shell.

and excute this:

```
sudo $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```